# probability with standard deviation

Tags: probability

On Green Island, twenty percent of all turtles survive for at least $4$ weeks after hatching. If the number of hatching this year is taken as $H$ and the number of turtles hatchings on Green Island is expected to increase by $10\%$ next year, show that the

1. standard deviation for the number of expected hatchings to survive at least $4$ weeks this year is $0.4\sqrt H$
2. average number of hatchings that will survive for at least $4$ weeks over the next two years will be $0.21H$

(hint: standard deviation for a year $= \sqrt{npq}$ and mean for a year $=np$)

Answer:

1. standard deviation $=\sqrt{npq}=\sqrt {H*0.2*0.8}=0.4\sqrt H$
2. $np=0.2H$ (but the answer shows $0.21H$)?

Comment: Over the next two years, not over the next year....

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, so p=0.2+(0.1)^2=0.21, but why we need to add them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This year there will be $H$ turtles hatching. The next year there will be $H+10\%H=1.1H$ turtles hatching. From them 20% will survive. So $$0.2(H+1.1H)=0.42H$$ Divide with $2$ to find the per year average.